# Windows installation issues on new PC

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installation, computer-building, windows-installer

I’ve just built a new PC and I’m trying to install windows. The only other working machine I have to hand is a Macbook running OSX so I used this method to create the installation USB: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-make-a-windows-10-usb-using-your-mac-build-a-bootable-iso-from-your-macs-terminal/

When I run the installer for the first time, I select the only storage device installed:

[image: storage select]

Then it try’s to run the install but throws this error:

[image: error]

When I restart the PC and rerun the installer, it shows that the partitions have been created:

[image: partitions]

But when I try and select the storage device I get this error:

[image: error 2]

The only way I can proceed is to delete all the partitions and start again, but then I just get the first error again.

I’ve tried this with windows 10 and 11 but both give the same results. I’ve also tried reformatting the drive from BIOS and cleaning the drive via command prompt but that didn’t help either. Any ideas what’s wrong here?

Comment: Does it let you format Drive 0 Partition 3, then proceed?

Comment: That gives the second error again ("couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one...")

Comment: Do you have any other hard drives or USB drives connected to the PC at the same time?

Comment: Can you try a simpler way of creating the bootable installer USB? See method 2 or Way 2 here https://www.makeuseof.com/create-windows-10-bootable-usb-mac-bootcamp/

Comment: @YisroelTech the only storage devices connected are the SSD and the installation USB. Bootcamp doesn't allow the creation of Windows installation USBs on my version of OSx (Big Sur 11.6) - only earlier OSx versions allow it. I did also try using UNetBootin but that didn't work either (different results/errors, but the issue seemed to be with the installation USB itself).

Comment: The current issue is also very likely "with the installation media itself" (so those errors might be relevant)

Comment: Thanks @YisroelTech, do you know of any other methods I can try to create an installation USB? I looked into PassFab 4Winkey but it no longer seems to offer a free version

Comment: Maybe follow https://medium.com/@maxi-mizer/creating-a-bootable-usb-windows-installer-on-a-mac-540a248e2983 he claims that he needed a combination of steps from the link you had and using UNetBootin

Comment: Thank you, I've actually managed to get the installation media working now. I ended up using BootCamp to install windows on my MacBook, then ran the media creation tool from within windows and that seems to have done the trick :)

Comment: You can put that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved this by using Bootcamp to install Windows dual boot on my Macbook, then used the Windows media creation tool from within Windows to create the installation USB.

Comment: Nice! Yes, i've been here myself and found bootcamp to be the most trouble free way to get windows installed on a mac.